# MPI_Bcast, broadcasting array buffer to specific locations in the receive buffer

Tags: c++, mpi

Using MPI, I want to do a broadcast operation by **all processes** in the communication group such that at the end of boradcast by all processes, the buffer in all processes have the same data.

Here is a fragment of code depicting what I want to do :

```
//assume there are 10 processes

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

double globalArray[100];
for(int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
   A[i] = (double)i + 1.0;
}

double buffer[10]; //assume all entries in buffer is zero

//only one array location in each rank is initialized and rest remain zero
buffer[rank] = globalArray[(rank + 1)*10]

MPI_Bcast(&buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
   std::cout << buffer[i] << "\t";
}

//expect to get [10 20  ... 100] in all the processes

MPI_Finalize();
```

I know there is MPI_Scatterv which on calling on each processor can do the work but this means I have to create two additional arrays, one for send_counts and displacements, which will always be the same for each scatterv operation.

Is there an easier way to do this ?

Comment: someone suggested MPI_Alltoall by using separate send and receive buffers but that doesn't ensure where in  the receive buffer the data goes to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly your question, what you really need is `MPI_Allgather()`

```
double myvalue = (rank + 1) * 10;
MPI_Allgather(&myvalue, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

MWE:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size, rank; 
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    double buffer[10]; 
    double myvalue = (rank + 1) * 10;
    MPI_Allgather(&myvalue, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) { 
        for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            std::cout << buffer[i] << "\t";
        }
    }

    // answer for all processes: 10 20 ... 100

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `myvalue` from task `i` is always stored in `buffer[i]`. If this is not what you expect, then please upload a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that validates the expected result. i must admit i have some hard time understanding what you expect.